# Stuck at gdata calendar parse exception in Android

Tags: android, calendar, android-widget, gdata

I am creating an widget to access the events stored in a google calendar.
Target : Android 2.1

I have included following external jar :

> google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar jsr305.jar
>
> gdata-calendar-2.0.jar,
>
> gdata-calendar-meta-2.0.jar,
>
> gdata-client-1.0.jar,
>
> gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar,
>
> gdata-core-1.0.jar

I get the following exception :

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException : org.xml.sax
```

here is my code: `HelloWidget.java`

```
package de.thesmile.android.widget2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import com.google.gdata.client.calendar.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import de.thesmile.android.widget2.R;

public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    int number =0;



    
public String gooleres()
{
    String result=new String("Unable to login into your account");
    // Create a CalenderService and authenticate
    try
    {
        URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

        CalendarQuery myQuery = new CalendarQuery(feedUrl);
        myQuery.setMinimumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-03-01T00:00:00"));
        myQuery.setMaximumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-03-06T23:59:59"));

        CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("wqewq");
        myService.setUserCredentials("sunnycool333@gmail.com", "XXXXXX");

         //Send the request and receive the response:
        Feed resultFeed = myService.query(myQuery, Feed.class);

        for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
          Entry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
          result= entry.getTitle().getPlainText().toString();
    }
        
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
        
        result="Exception raised "+e.toString();
    }
        return result;
        
}



    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        
    
        
         
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        
                 
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, gooleres());
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            
        }
        
    }


}
```

The code seems to be proper because when I try to put the same code as simple java file then I do get the output..
the simple java file I created looks something like this and it gives proper output..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    // Create a CalenderService and authenticate
    
    
    try
    {
    
    URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

    CalendarQuery myQuery = new CalendarQuery(feedUrl);
    myQuery.setMinimumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-03-01T00:00:00"));
    myQuery.setMaximumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2011-03-08T23:59:59"));

    CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
    myService.setUserCredentials("sunnycool333@gmail.com", "ytrfvgb$");

    // Send the request and receive the response:
    Feed resultFeed = myService.query(myQuery, Feed.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
      Entry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
      
      System.out.println(Integer.toString(i)+entry.getTitle().getPlainText().toString());
      
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    
    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdata api is not supported fully by android..

so have to move to google java client library  :(